# Table of images with automatic scaling

Tags: tables, graphics

How to create a table of images so that every column has exactly the same width and images are scaled to fit the width (with aspect ratio kept)? Assuming that I choose the table width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\resizebox` calls in a `tabular`-like environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry} % demo only
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu}{X[m]X[m]X[m]X[m]X[m]X[m]}
\resizebox{\hsize}{!}{\includegraphics[width=6cm, height=3cm]{}} &
\resizebox{\hsize}{!}{\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=3cm]{}} &
\resizebox{\hsize}{!}{\includegraphics[width=4cm, height=3cm]{}} &
\resizebox{\hsize}{!}{\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=3cm]{}} &
\resizebox{\hsize}{!}{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=3cm]{}} &
\resizebox{\hsize}{!}{\includegraphics[width=1cm, height=3cm]{}}
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Note 1: Vertical alignment can be changed in the column list of tabu.

Note 2: You should remove the `demo` option of `graphicx` to have pictures included (instead of black boxes).

Comment: Think this sufficiently answered my question. Thanks!